# what does C# mysql command.ExecuteNonQuery returns? if its a delete operation

Tags: c#, mysql

```
string deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM processedscanlog WHERE processedscanlog_id = @LOGID";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOGID", log_id);
command.CommandText = deleteQuery;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Put a break point, assign the value back to an object and see what you get.

Comment: See the [ExecuteNotQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, which explains the expected result. If the MySQL provider behaves differently it should cover any such differences in [its own documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/).

Comment: Oops, see [IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) - but same idea.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) Documentation it returns an int that is the number of rows affected

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command .. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: Dont thinks that for MySQL...

Comment: @KayNelson If it does not, then it is a broken implementation or broken documentation (in MySQL). FWIW, [MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommandmembers.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlcommand-executenonquery) does not specify non-expected/default behavior from [IDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Got it.thanks for explanation.